# Cordova: HTTP GET doesn't work in Android

Tags: android, cordova, cors, http-get

I'm developing a mobile app on Cordova. The main code communicates with a local server through HTTP GET, for example:

```
    $.get( "http://192.168.2.6:8080/getStatus.sha",
        {},
        function(data) {
            alert ("checkIpAddress() success! Status: " + data.status);
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert ("checkIpAddress() failed to get url \'" + url + "\'.");
        });
```

When I run that code on Mozilla Firefox, I get the server staus (and more data).

But when I run the Cordova program on an Android device, I get the "checkIpAddress() failed" message.

The local server supports CORS. The Crodova project's config.xml has these settings:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
```

Any suggestions to fix the error? Thanks!

Comment: Is the device on the same network? Does the local server have a statically assigned IP?

Comment: Yes, on the same WiFi.

Comment: Which Cordova version?  Configuration for allowed network access changed, see my answer for Cordova 5.

Comment: The server address is configurable through the mobiel app, I'm testing it with FIrefox and works fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Cordova 5 and the device and server can see each other (on same wifi network) you likely have to enable this with the content security policy. See [Cordova Whitelist Plugin.](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist)  You want to consider adding a meta tag to

Example configuration would look like:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Depending on what else your app does or doesn't do you may not need all other options in the above, although some Ajax and templating frameworks will.  The above works for a Cordova 5 app using JQuery and Handlebars.

Comment: Ok, I added the Content-Security-Policy tag to the main.html and put the corresponding asterisks. Thanks!

Comment: If that works for you please go ahead and accept the answer or let us know if there are still issues.  Thanks.

Comment: "Thanks for your feedback! Once you earn a total reputation of 15 reputation, your votes will appear."

I'm sorry I can't vote up your answer.